# In Python , If a member of a class is of list type , then how to protect that list from other objects

Tags: python, oop

I have a class in python, which has a member of type list.
My assumption is that this list type member is specific to the object instantiated from the class.
But in my code , all the objects are sharing this list type.
How to protect it from other objects? Or am I doing some mistake in my code.

My expectation from the following code is that Student "Alex" should have "Maths" and "Science" books with him. Bob should have none. But this code prints both Alex and Bob have both "Maths" and "Science" books.

I am new to OOP with Python, I assume that it is similar to CPP.
What is going wrong with the following code or correct me if I am wrong in my assumptions.

```
class Book:
    Title=""
    NoOfPages = 0

class Student:
    nameOfStudent = ""
    listOfBooks = list()
    def __init__(self,studentName):
        self.nameOfStudent = studentName
    def AddBook(self,nameOfBook,pages):
        b = Book()
        b.Title = nameOfBook
        b.NoOfPages = pages
        self.listOfBooks.append(b)
    def Print(self):
        print(self.nameOfStudent + " has " + str(len(self.listOfBooks)) + " Books\n")
        for book in self.listOfBooks:
            print("    " + book.Title + "\n")


s1 = Student("Alex")
s1.AddBook("Maths",100)
s1.AddBook("Science",120)

s2 = Student("Bob")

s1.Print()
s2.Print()
```

Comment: Initialize `listOfBooks` inside `__init__`, just like `self.nameOfStudent`.

Comment: ``listOfBooks`` is specific to *the single ``class``* Student, because that's where you defined it. It's not specific to *each* object instantiated from the class.

Comment: Added the following initialization, still same out put                                                  `def __init__(self,studentName):
        self.nameOfStudent = studentName
        listOfBooks = list() `

Comment: self.listOfBooks not just listOfBooks

Comment: Yes, it worked with `self.listOfBooks'. Thanks